# SQL GO disrupts chain of local variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, variables

I use script for DB backup as below:

```
---- INITIALIZATION

-- UNIFIED DATE
DECLARE @DAT DATETIME
SELECT @DAT =  GETDATE()

-- DEFAULT BACKUPS LOCATION
DECLARE @PATH VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @PATH = 'Q:\DBbackup\Default\'

---- DATABASE BACKUPS

-- DB1
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(64)
SELECT @DBNAME = 'DB1'
DECLARE @BACKUPNAME VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (255)
SELECT @BACKUPNAME = (@PATH + @DBNAME +'_'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@DAT,121) + '.bak')
SELECT @DESCRIPTION = @DBNAME + ' Full ad hoc backup ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@DAT)
SELECT @BACKUPNAME
BACKUP DATABASE @DBNAME TO  DISK = @BACKUPNAME WITH FORMAT, INIT,  NAME = @DESCRIPTION, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10, COMPRESSION
GO

-- DB2
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(64)
SELECT @DBNAME = 'DB2'
DECLARE @BACKUPNAME VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (255)
SELECT @BACKUPNAME = (@PATH + @DBNAME + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@DAT,121) + '.bak')
SELECT @DESCRIPTION = @DBNAME + ' Full ad hoc backup ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@DAT)
BACKUP DATABASE @DBNAME TO  DISK = @BACKUPNAME WITH FORMAT, INIT,  NAME = @DESCRIPTION, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10, COMPRESSION
GO
```

However, for backup DB2 the variables `@PATH` and `@DAT` are not found as they apply only to first backup. It seems the `GO` command cancels the effect of local variables for `DB2` backup. Is there any workaround for this situation? I want to use the variables in `INIT` only once, not duplicate them for each database backup.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not know what `GO` means. That's an SSMS feature. It causes multiple batches to be sent. Either remove `GO` (and restructure the variables so that they are declared only once) or store that data in a persistent location such as a temp table.

Unfortunately, no great options. T-SQL is a stone-age language.